# Which modulation does radio walkie talkie work on?

Tags: communication, radio

On which radio band does walkie talkie work on? Is it amplitude modification,  frequency modulation, or short way modulation?

Comment: The band it works on is all of them. If you have a *specific* model, it will work on a specific band, but an arbitrary "walkie talkie" could conceivably work on any (or all) bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies, depending on the country and the walkie-talkie.

In India, you can get walkie-talkies operating on 136-174 MHz (VHF High band), 400-470 MHz (UHF), and 350-390 MHz (UHF, possibly specific to India).  These units are frequency-modulated, at 8 kHz and 16 kHz deviation.

136-174 MHz and 400-470 MHz are pretty standard industrial allocations, but CHECK WITH YOUR LOCAL AUTHORITIES before you transmit.  There may be licensing requirements, and the potential penalties for unlicensed transmitter operation are usually draconian, to put it mildly.

You can also get really cheap toy units, that run on 49 MHz.  They're probably AM rigs, with superregenerative receivers (translation: junkie-talkies), but they MIGHT be FM rigs.

Comment: Receiving is noto an issue, trsansmitting is.

Comment: Certain devices will have proprietary encoded protocols such as police or military. To stop randoms like you from listening in!

Comment: @KashifKhan, we can't tell you what the laws are in your country.  You need to check with your local authorities.  If you are hesitant to do that, because you already know that you are planning to do something illegal, you probably should think long and hard about what you want to do and whether you really want a long all-expenses-paid vacation in a government-operated zero-stars hotel.

Comment: @VladimirCravero, it depends.  Some places outlaw even receiving, at least for some kinds of radio communication.  In the United States, intercepting a cellular telephone call is VERY illegal.  (However, there has been at least one case in which a police officer using a scanning receiver discovered a crime in progress, and went and arrested the perps.  During the trial, the prosecution was forced to concede that the officer's interception of the call was VERY illegal.  The officer was never charged with anything.)

Comment: I don't get how is it possible do intercept and decode a cellular phone call. They are coded for a reason...

Comment: @KashifKhan: If, for example, your intent is to monitor for and intercept police walkie-talkie communications, so that you will not be surprised when they attempt to break up your "party", you might want to reconsider your plans.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: GSM cellphones are encrypted.  TDMA and CDMA cellphones aren't.  TDMA cellphone calls can be intercepted with a simple scanning receiver.  CDMA takes a more sophisticated receiver, just to cope with the CDMA signal, but there is no actual encryption in CDMA.  (Note: A math professor at UT Austin presented a talk in 2003 or 2004, to the undergrad Math Club, explaining a HUGE screwup in GSM encryption.  He characterized the error as "so bad it had to be deliberate".)

Comment: yep I know how cdma works, it is not actually encrypted but guessing the code should be quite hard... I guess I was wrong then

Comment: @VladimirCravero, CDMA is not simple, but it is not magic.  Every CDMA cellphone comes up and has to sync with the base station, to get the coding and start talking.